# Storing circular objects in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose, socket.io

I am using socket.io module for Node.js for communication between users. What I want is: once a specific user establishes connection, I need to store his/her socket in database, so that in case I need it, I can send message to him/her at arbitrary moment in time. So, since I can have hundreds of users, I wanted to store their socket objects in database.
For this purpose, I used Schema type Mixed, since sockets are Objects. However, sockets are **circular** objects, so my stack overflows when trying to store socket in database. I am interested in this: is it possible to store such circular objects in MongoDB? I managed to store sockets in variables and reuse them later to send messages using them, so this is possible if I store these sockets in some data structures, but I am interested whether they can be stored in the database? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not possible to store circular objects, also storing socket id in database is totally wrong because it changes in time and will be useless.

What you can do and (you should do) is create room for users:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // you are emitting this event from client with your choose of identifier
    socket.on('auth', function(userId) {       
        socket.join('room:' + userId)   
    })

})
```

And then you can emit events to specific user since you are creating a private room for that user, with `userId` etc:

```
var userId = 1234
io.in('room:' + userId).emit('hello', { 'asd': 'xxx' });
```